# CConn: unable connect to socket: Connection refused (111)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, vnc, remmina

I have a Raspberry Pi4 with Ubuntu 19.10 installed and am using it headless via ssh from a Linux laptop.

I want access to a vncserver and have installed tightvncserver following [this guide](https://www.fosslinux.com/17674/how-to-install-vnc-server-on-ubuntu.htm)

I have used remmina with the address localhost:5901 and:

```
makem@ssdTOSH:~$ vncviewer 192.168.2.73:5901

TigerVNC Viewer 64-bit v1.7.0
Built on: 2017-12-05 09:25
Copyright (C) 1999-2016 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.txt)
See http://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.

Wed Nov  6 00:13:23 2019
 DecodeManager: Detected 4 CPU core(s)
 DecodeManager: Creating 4 decoder thread(s)
 CConn:       unable connect to socket: Connection refused (111)
```

I always get this error and any suggestions to remedy this would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same problem 2.5 years later,, hope we get an answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me while the VNC server was not started. I had an error in the config file; luckily I found out where the log is to find that out.

The running TigerVNC server from ArchLinux shows up like this, after I got it working (`systemctl status vncserver@:1`):

```
● vncserver@:1.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/vncserver@.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2023-11-18 04:36:49 EET; 8min ago
```